# Sliding Two Points Along Perpendicular Slope By Distance

Tags: math, geometry

For my current project, a user taps 2 locations on the X,Y plane. Once the two points are tapped, the user should then click and drag to extend 2 new points starting at the original 2 locations into a perfect rectangle (90 degree corners).

The math seems super simple, I just can't seem to get the right configuration to slide these two points along the perpendicular slope (by a certain distance).

My current attempt is to find the perpendicular slope and slide it by X distance (the distance the user has dragged), but I'm stuck on translating the perp. slope by distance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have points A and B. Difference vector

```
D = (Dx, Dy) = (Bx - Ax, By - Ay)
```

Normalized (unit) vector

```
 Len = Sqrt(Dx*Dx + Dy*Dy)
(dx, dy) = (Dx / Len, Dy / Len)
```

Perpendicular unit vector

```
(px, py) = (-dy, dx)
```

Shift by distance L

```
pL = (px * L, py * L)
```

So shifted A will have coordinates

```
 (a'x, a'y) = (Ax +/- px * L, Bx +/- py * L)
```

`+` or `-` for two possible shift directions